# php time periods without weekends

Tags: php, date

Given the date of a day and a number (X) of days I'd need to retrieve the date after X days without considering Saturdays or Sundays.

For example:

```
date1= Y-m-d   -where->   Monday of the week #20
date1+2 days=  Wednesday of the week #20

date2= Friday of the week #22
date2+1 day= Monday of week #23
```

Is there some built-in function for helping with that task? or must I implement it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to write it your own. Which should you be able to do faster than waiting for some answer.

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#101379

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work ([demo](http://codepad.org/6TPddPLU)):

```
$date = strtotime('2012-06-01'); // Friday

echo date('Y-m-d (l)', strtotime('+1 weekdays', $date)); // 2012-06-04 (Monday)
echo date('Y-m-d (l)', strtotime('+6 weekdays', $date)); // 2012-06-11 (Monday)
echo date('Y-m-d (l)', strtotime('+8 weekdays', $date)); // 2012-06-13 (Wednesday)
echo date('Y-m-d (l)', strtotime('+9 weekdays', $date)); // 2012-06-14 (Thursday)
echo date('Y-m-d (l)', strtotime('+10 weekdays', $date)); // 2012-06-17 (Sunday)
```

Sorry, but I don't know what's wrong with the last one; perhaps someone else can shed some light into it.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: Actually, no: it goes from `Thu` to `Sun`. =\

Comment: Maybe it's got to do with locale, setting a default timezone may fix that.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: I smell a `strtotime` bug but let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: No, even setting that won't change the interpretation of *weekdays* --  PHP insists on the Jewish weekend days. http://codepad.org/YfNoFEdg

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: I would submit a bug report.

Comment: After you do, would be nice to post a link to the bug report here too.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: Oh, I said that I *would* (as in, if I were you), but ok.